# avoiding comments by c lexical analyzer

Tags: c, flex-lexer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem getting c-style comments in flex/lex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130097/problem-getting-c-style-comments-in-flex-lex)

I am writing a lexical analyzer using flex how can I make it avoid the comments that look
like this:

```
/* COMMENTS */
```

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur: If the question is about "flex", then the asker is already using regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bit complicated. Here is a solution I found:

```
<INITIAL>{
"/*"              BEGIN(IN_COMMENT);
}
<IN_COMMENT>{
"*/"      BEGIN(INITIAL);
[^*\n]+   // eat comment in chunks
"*"       // eat the lone star
\n        yylineno++;
} { return COMMENT; }
```

The "obvious" solution, something like this:

```
"/*".*"*/" { return COMMENT; }
```

will match too much.

Comment: But what if the comment was something like this /*\n*/ the "." will match every character except the newline which is "\n" and what does the { return COMMENT; } do? where does it return? cant I do just like this "/*".*"*/"       ;

Comment: Flex-generated scanners are greedy, and will match as much as possible, so **"/*".*"*/"** would match all of **/*foo*/fum*/** and not just **/*foo*/.** The **{ return COMMENT; }** part just returns the token code from the Flex-generated scanner. In most cases you'll want to ignore comments, and then you should remove the return statement.

Comment: If the flex scanner is greedy as you have said so the "obvious" solution above is so wrong because of this as an example:/* a comment */ do_my_thing( "oops */" );

Comment: Yes, as I wrote: The "obvious" solution will match too much. Or do I misunderstand you?