# Flex lexer output modification

Tags: c++, parsing, token, lexer, flex-lexer

How can I use flex lexer in C++ and modify a token's `yytext` value?
Lets say, I have a rule like this:

```
"/*"    {
        char c;
        while(true)
            {
            c = yyinput();
            if(c == '\n')
                ++mylineno;

            if (c==EOF){
                yyerror( "EOF occured while processing comment" );
                break;
            }
            else if(c == '*')
                {
                if((c = yyinput()) == '/'){
                    return(tokens::COMMENT);}
                else
                    unput(c);
                }
            }
        }
```

And I want to get token `tokens::COMMENT` with value of comment between `/*` and `*/`.
(The bove solution gives "/*" as the value.

Additional, very important is tracking the line number, so I'm looking for solution supporting it.

**EDIT**
Of course I can modify the `yytext` and `yyleng` values (like `yytext+=1; yyleng-=1`, but still I cannot solve the above problem)

Comment: Do you have a parser taking tokens from here. or it just lexer only? You can solve this easily in the parser.

Comment: I really would like to solve it in the lexer - is it possible?

Comment: Check out this existing answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2130124/1003855

Comment: Sorry, but there is no answer to my question :(

Comment: @danilo2 ok. Then how do you handle strings? do you have some pool to store them in? or show me how you recognize a string literal.

Comment: Strings have the same problem while using flex - I have to read the substring in "parser" not "tokenizer", because tokenizer cannot return string without front and back quotations - but if it could, this problem would be solved also (and the string handling would be nicer)

Comment: Yes but if you have some way of recognizing `"somethin"` as string I have suggested an answer for you. Take a look.

Comment: @stardust_ - Of course I have and of course it is easly solvable in parser, BUT *the lexer is responsible for outputing tokens with good values* - If I have to change the values *later* this is not pure design.

Answer (score 1):

I still think start conditions are the right answer.

```
%x C_COMMENT
char *str = NULL;
void addToString(char *data)
{
    if(!str)
    { 
        str = strdup(data);
    }
    else
    {
        /* handle string concatenation */
    }
}

"/*"                       { BEGIN(C_COMMENT); }
<C_COMMENT>([^*\n\r]|(\*+([^*/\n\r])))*    { addToString(yytext); }
<C_COMMENT>[\n\r]          { /* handle tracking, add to string if desired */ }
<C_COMMENT>"*/"            { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
```

I used the following as references:
http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2130124/1003855

You should be able to use a similar regular expression to handle strings.

Comment: Your solutin do not track the line number. So if you want to get place information, you cannot do it.

Comment: If that's a requirement, then I will modify my code to support it.

Comment: Yes it is (I updated the question), so if you know the answer, I'll be thankful for it.